# Bootstrap Navbar, with logo, centered links, do not remain vertically aligned after window resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, I am trying to make use of bootstrap's api for a responsive design, however I think I started off on the wrong foot. So I have a problem. You can check out my site on http://www.nationalbloodservicemt.we.bs and clearly understand the issue i'm having.

**Issue 1:** 
First of all, the centered links and social media icons are not vertically aligned with the logo, and I can't seem to get it to align properly even with the `.nav` element with a property of inline-block.

**Issue 2 :** 
After the window is resized and bootstrap does its magic and media queries kick in, when the window is brought back to full screen or larger than the specified media query, the `.nav-collapse` element fails to position itself inline with the logo,  instead it goes  right beneath it.

How can I fix these issues? Also I have a separate file for custom stylesheet, which overrides some bootstrap elements. Should I just edit the bootstrap.css directly? (Is it a better practice?) Sorry I am a newbie to bootstrap.

Comment: Can you try to comment out your stylesheet that overrides bootstrap and see if your second issue still persists? And no, do NOT edit bootstrap directly. That's not good practice! :)

Comment: Hi @domdev, I commented out all custom css and it still persists. Ok so I asked because I find it quite challenging to figure out which style in bootstrap css, that is overriding my style. Which then I end up using !important, which I hear is evil in some cases.

Comment: If you place your CSS stylesheet after the bootstrap CSS stylesheet in your document you don't need !important to override.

Comment: You should also implement the navbar as it is suggested on the Bootstrap site. I can see that you use a slightly different mark-up. See here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Oh. The markup is from the layout example, called the hero unit. I went with that since it seemed one of the simplest layouts, which can easily be customised (or so I thought..)

Comment: @domdev, interesting to not that  If i toggle(off and back on) the `position: absolute !important;` attribute  for the `
.nav-collapse.collapse ` element, from chrome dev tools, it takes effect and positioned appropriately. Which is strange.. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I am enforcing the alignments of navbar-collapse by adding a float: left to the logo element. I have not completely tested this and might be a complete flop or at the very least carry some repercussions. but for now, it will do. If anyone has a better solution/workaround, i'm interested to hear about it .